# SOQL returns nickname instead of User.Name for partner user

Tags: soql, soap-api, partner-portal

I've a following SOQL query which returns name for regular users.

```
SELECT Name,Title,Email FROM User
```

But it returns nickname for the partner users. I've made sure to turn off the "Show nicknames" and turn on the "See other members of this site" under the preferences of Administration.

[image]

[image]

I've come across this [link](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ0UYAA0/spring-19-communitypartner-users-not-able-to-fetch-standard-name-field-of-the-user-via-soql-from-lighting-component-in-community) which is tagged as resolved. But I am still facing the issue.

Please let me know what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include some important details.  How are you executing this query - in Apex, Developer Workbench, API call, or something else?  What type of user is executing the query - enterprise user or partner user?  Please [edit] your post.  Also the link you posted doesn't refer to nickname, so it is probably not related.